# Find out the direct assigned licenses of an o365 user

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I am trying to write a powershell script, where I need to remove the licenses of the user. However, I only need to **remove the license if it is assigned directly and not via some Azure group**. I do not have to touch the licenses which are showing up because of group based policy.

While testing, I noted that for the licenses property of a msoluser there also exists GroupsAssingningLicense which I could explore, however it contains value even for direct assign licenses.

Is there way I can figure out if the license is a direct assign or is showing up due to user being part of some group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direction is correct.

We really should filter according to `GroupsAssingningLicense`.

For a direct assigned license, the value of `GroupsAssingningLicense` is the object id of the **user**.

But for an inherited assigned license, the value of `GroupsAssingningLicense` is the object id of the **group**.

A sample for your reference:

```
Connect-MsolService

$username = ""

$user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $username

foreach ($license in $user.Licenses){
    if($license.GroupsAssigningLicense[0].ToString() -eq $user.ObjectId){
        Write-Host $license.AccountSkuId
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses $license.AccountSkuId
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Allen, I hope I had found this earlier, I wouldn't have to pull a whole night. Really appreciate this

Comment: I do have one doubt though, for some of the users, I do see that GroupsAssingningLicense object is empty, any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: @KaranParikh I didn't see such a scene from my side. Can you provide any screenshots of what you see in Powershell and Azure portal?

Comment: I hope there was some way of sharing a screenshot, imgur is blocked for me. I will try to share the code that I execute at Powershell

`$UPN = "<UPN_OF_User>"

$msolUser = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN
$msolUser.Licenses | Select AccountSKUId, GroupsAssigningLicense | fl`

and for it the output I receive is 

`AccountSkuId           : tenant:ENTERPRISEPACK
GroupsAssigningLicense : {}`

the license SKU is correct, but I wonder why the groupassigninglicense is empty, on the microsoft portal as well, I can see the same license.

Comment: @KaranParikh Sorry for that I can't reproduce this issue. You could dig into to find which kind of the license will have this scene. Good luck!